# Need help for default value for Quantity column in C# datagrid view and it should be changeable

Tags: c#, datagridview

In windows form c# datagridvew I make it default value, for sales invoice form. I set default value of 1 for quantity, but if I want to change it I can't; when I click after editend it becomes 1 again for all rows:

```
//Only for Default Value
private void dgvitemDetail_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvitemDetail.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow) break;
        row.Cells[5].Value = "1";
    }
}
```

Comment: To make item's highlighted as code, they need to have 4 spaces at the beginning of the line, or you can highlight your code and click the code button in the editor

Comment: The code is looping through all the rows and setting cell five (5) to 1. This is done for all rows except the “new” row? I am not sure why you would expect something else and this is not really setting a ‘default’ value for a “new” row. I am guessing it may be better to wire up the grids `DefaultValuesNeeded` event. This event will fire when the user “clicks” a cell in the “new” row. In the event, add the line:    `e.Row.Cells[5].Value = "1";` … this should set the new rows cell five (5) to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want "break;" you want "continue;"

"Continue" tells the code to skip everything and go to the next item in the list.
"Break" tells switch statements that it's the end of this sections of code.

Few examples:

```
for (var animal in animals)
{
  if (animal == "cat") continue;

  Console.WriteLine("Is not a cat!");
}
```

And a switch statement:

```
switch (animal)
{
    case "cat":
      Console.WriteLine("I'm a cat!!");
      break;
    default:
      Console.WriteLine("I wish I was a cat!");
      break;
}
```

I think you want:

```
void dgvitemDetail_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{ 
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvitemDetail.Rows) 
    { 
        if (row.IsNewRow) continue;

        row.Cells[5].Value = "1";
    }
}
```

or even better:

```
void dgvitemDetail_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{ 
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvitemDetail.Rows) 
    { 
        // 0 = if it's a new row and 1 = a preexisting row
        row.Cells[5].Value = row.IsNewRow ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```